# Problem at Downloading from Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: installation

I have 12.04. The problem is that when downloading and installing from the Software Center is almost finished, I get this error message:

**installing software package failed.**

It happens to me every time I'm installing a software, so no software that I decided to install from Ubuntu Software Center is installed on my PC .

Please help.

Comment: Can you try installing via apt-get? Open a terminal and pop in `sudo apt-get install` *`<packagename>`* .

Comment: see the details option in Error window . paste that error details here. it could help us to better understand your problem .

Answer (score 0):

Go to your preferences and set up your proxy from there (if you are using one this is). Make sure the system (not the internet browser is connected) to the outer world, then try it over again.

Comment: Just corrected your English. The contents of your post does not seem right either tough.

Comment: This does not appear to be factually correct.